# Python find numbers between range in list or array

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, numpy

I have a list with millions of numbers which are always increasing to the end, I need to find and return numbers within a specified range e.g. numbers greater than X but less than Y, the numbers in the list can change and the values I'm searching for change as well

I have been using this method, please note this is a basic example the numbers are not uniform or the same as shown below in my program

```
l = [i for i in range(2000000)]
nums = []
for element in l:
    if element > 950004:
        break
    if element > 950000:
        nums.append(element)
#[950001, 950002, 950003, 950004]
```

Although fast, I kind of need it to be a bit faster for what my program is doing, the numbers change a lot so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this with a pandas series or a numpy array? but so far all I've done is make an example in numpy:

```
a = numpy.array(l,dtype=numpy.int64)
```

Would a pandas series be more functional? Making use of query()? what would be the best way to approach this with an array as opposed to a python list of python objects

Comment: Are you trying to filter your list to numbers between a set of values?

Comment: no, sorry, return values between x and y

Comment: it seems that you're just trying to extract a slice from `950000` to `950004`. What is the point?

Comment: Maybe, searching for the indices of the range-bounds with binary search would make it faster.

Comment: Could you update your example to be closer to your actual problem?

Comment: is this a problem of choosing the two numbers every time you run the script?

Comment: Are the values sorted in increasing order?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman yes always that's why it can break safely once reaching a value which is greater than the stop value

Comment: @new_to_coding As @Caculator stated, a solution based on the binary search algorithm can be interesting. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681948/get-index-of-closest-value-with-binary-search), the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) package was suggested in the comments. As I understand your question, this package pretty much solves it.

Comment: @Unatiel indeed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution using binary search. You are speaking of millions of numbers. Technically binary search will make the algorithm faster by decreasing the runtime complexity to O(log n) neglecting the final slicing step.

```
import bisect

l = [i for i in range(2000000)]
lower_bound = 950000
upper_bound = 950004

lower_bound_i = bisect.bisect_left(l, lower_bound)
upper_bound_i = bisect.bisect_right(l, upper_bound, lo=lower_bound_i)
nums = l[lower_bound_i:upper_bound_i]
```

Comment: somehow it's slightly quicker than the numpy boolean slice O_o;

Comment: thank you, I would probably not have found this solution browsing the docs

Comment: This can be made even more efficient by using a `lo=lower_bound_i` argument in `bisect.bisect_right`.

Comment: @new_to_coding this list-slice, you mean? Yeah, a boolean slice *creates a whole boolean array the size of your current array*. A Python list-slice is extremely fast and efficient, implemented in C.

Answer (score 3):

The following are two implementations for binary search (based on code from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81188-binary-search/)) - one which searches for an upper limit and one which searches for a lower limit. Does this work better for you?

```
def binary_search_upper(seq, limit):
    min = 0
    max = len(seq) - 1
    while True:
        if max < min:
            return -1
        m = (min + max) / 2
        if m == (len(seq) -1) or (seq[m] <= limit and seq[m+1] > limit):
            return m
        elif seq[m] < limit:
            min = m+1
        else:
            max = m - 1

def binary_search_lower(seq, limit):
    min = 0
    max = len(seq) - 1
    while True:
        if max < min:
            return -1
        m = (min + max) / 2
        if m == 0 or (seq[m] >= limit and seq[m-1] < limit):
            return m
        elif seq[m] < limit:
            min = m+1
        else:
            max = m - 1


l = [i for i in range(2000000)]
print binary_search_upper(l, 950004)
print binary_search_lower(l, 950000)
```

Comment: Why would you use this recipe, which is over 14 years old, and not the standard-library implementation (which will have much, *much* better constant factors)?

Comment: JFTR, this is about ten times slower than `bisect`.

Comment: @ekhumoro interesting, where can I learn more about how `bisect` is so fast?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman. The [source code for the module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) shows a pure python implementation, but the [real implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_bisectmodule.c) is written in C.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman. PS: the pure python bisect implementation is about twice as fast as yours :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy to get a subset of your list using a boolean slice.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(2000000)
nums = a[(950000<a) & (a<=950004)]
nums
# returns
array([950001, 950002, 950003, 950004])
```

Comment: the numbers are not the same in my program, this is a basic example, sorry

Comment: This takes all the numbers in the entire array, and does not exit after hitting the stop condition.