# Answer queries about the number of distinct numbers in a given range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-indexed-tree

The problem

I have an array with N numbers. The numbers may be disctints and may also be unordered. I have to answer Q queries about how many distinct numbers there are between A and B. Where A, B are indices between 0 <= A <= B < array.Length.

I know how to do it O(N) per query by using a HashTable but I'm asking for a more efficient solution.
I tried to improve it with sqrt decomposition and also with a segment tree but I couldn't. I'm not showing any code because I did not find any idea that worked.
I'm looking for someone to give an explanation of a faster solution.

**UPDATE**

I read you can collect the queries and then answer them all by using a Binary Indexed Tree (BIT). Can someone explain how to do it. Assume I know how a BIT works.

Comment: What do you mean by `different numbers` in between A and B. If it's about how many numbers ie. range, then Why not just Use `B-A-1`

Comment: If you have a list, and two arbitrary numbers, and you want to find the numbers in the list between those two numbers, you can use binary search, with a time complexity of `O(logn)`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980453/3483203) is a great answer to get you started.

Comment: @chrisz It's asking for the amount of **distinct** numbers, which can't be done in less than O(n) (since any given element can be a duplicate or distinct, thus we need to look at every element) if it needs to be done from scratch (that is, if the question were asking for 1 instead of Q queries).

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: You can find something here: https://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=RevisionHistory&messageID=1369039
But it's true there is not a proper explanation, this is more an efficient working code.

Comment: @chrisz can you read again? I updated the text

Comment: Wait you just want to know based on indices? So like in a length 10 array, how many unique numbers fall between the second and eighth index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each index `i` find the previous index `prev[i]` that has the same value (or -1 if there's no such index). It may be done in `O(n)` average by going left to right with hash_map, then the answer for range [l;r) of indices is number of elements `i` in range [l;r) such that their value is less then `l` (it require some thinking but should be clear)

Now we will solve problem "given range `[l;r)` and value `c` find number of elements that are less then `c`" on array `prev`. It may be done in `O(log^2)` using segment tree, if we save in each vertex all the numbers that are in its range(subtree). (On each query we will get `O(log n)` vertices and do binary search in them)